# Change include paths

Tags: c++, visual-c++, msbuild

I have a C++ solution that uses several external libraries. For that to work, the compiler needs to be able to find all the header files. Currently this works by hard-coding the header locations into the various project files. But since the headers are installed in a different location on each computer, that means the project will only build on one machine.

What is the "correct" way to deal with this problem?

I feel like there should be a way to define which libraries each project needs, and then a separate file somewhere that says where those libraries are on this particular machine. But I don't know if MSBuild has anything remotely like that.

(Obviously, as well as the header files, we have exactly the same problem with the linker needing to find the object code to link in.)

Comment: Would you happen to be using cmake or anything similar? Or just VS Solution/Projects?

Comment: @ChrisMM Just a normal VS solution. I don't even know what CMake is.

Comment: _CMake is an open-source, cross-platform family of tools designed to build, test and package software. CMake is used to control the software compilation process using simple platform and compiler independent configuration files_ [CMake](https://cmake.org/) and other similar tools are used for this purpose, so that each machine will have correct paths for their environment. CMake will create the .sln and .vcproj files for you with the correct paths set up. As far as I know, there is no way to do this using just the Solution/Project files (though I may be wrong).

Comment: You can define a system (PC-specific) environment variable, say `$MyIncludePath`, then use that as an 'extra' include directory in your VC project(s). I'll need to check up on details ...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems you can in fact fix this using environment variables. Either through the Visual Studio user interface itself, or just by editing the `*.vcxproj` file in a text editor, edit the include path from

```
D:\Libraries\Boost\32bit\include;D:\Libraries\GTest\32bit\include
```

to instead be something like

```
$(BOOST_ROOT)\include;$(GTEST_ROOT)\include
```

Now the project builds on any machine where the environment variable `%BOOST_ROOT%` is set to the right folder path. (And likewise for `%GTEST_ROOT%`.)

Comment: This idea also works for the library path you pass to the linker. (of course not `$FOO\include`, check where your library stores the `.LIB` )